# IIS server slows down with only a few tens of requests

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, fastcgi

I'm using IIS 7.5 with PHP and I'm having troubles with my application, it is VERY slow and it can take more than 30 seconds to respond sometimes.

I believe this is due to some kind of queue of requests to process.

I've taken a look at the "Worker Processes" menu in IIS and I found out there are tends of request in the *DefaultAppPool*.
I though servers could handle hundreds or thousands of requests, so I'm a bit surprised to find out the server slows down so much with just a few tens of requests.

Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: Are all these requests to the same website? Have you tried splitting each website into its own AppPool? Remember that if any one of the websites on an AppPool fail such that the failure will cause the AppPool to stop, then every website on it will also stop.

Comment: They are all the same website yeah.

Comment: @Steve have you found its solution? I'm having the same issue.